# evento focus para mobile - javascript

Tags: javascript, html

alguem sabe me dizer pq o evento focus nao funciona em mobile?

Não achei em lugar nenhum nada falando sobre isso..

tenho um input na pagina que recebe o foco normalmente.. em desktop esta tudo funcionando...

qnd entro via mobile.. no safari ou chrome.. o campo não recebe o foco..

usei o autofocus no próprio input, ou via javascript o elemtno via .focus() ambos funcionam apenas no desktop..

valeu

Comment: Claro que funciona! Acesse esse link no celular: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus

Comment: Tente reproduzir teu problema em um fiddle ou StackSnippet.

Comment: Sim, mas eu precisei clicar no botão para o foco Ir para o input.. no meu caso qnd a página é carregada o foco já deve estar no campo.. isso n acontece..

Comment: Por favor forneça um código específico para o seu problema.